# How to get ViewID on TouchUp Event

Tags: android, textview

I'm implementing Drag Drop of one text view to other text view. I've created OnTouchListener and applied on my both TextViews

I wrote OnTouch Function like this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
    {
        switch(e.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                        
                Log.d("Down",v.getId()+"");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                        
                 Log.d("Move",v.getId()+"");
                 break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                       
                 Log.d("Up",v.getId()+"");
                 break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'm facing a problem in all three cases it returns me ID of the TextView on which first time the touch event is fired. I want to obtain the IDs of other TextViews
For example it just give me ID of Down Event "tv1". And again gives me "tv1" on Move Event and Up Event (despite of my position is changed to other TextView whose ID is tv2)

How can i get the ID of TextView on which Touch Up Event has occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically you should not expect up event of tv2 . because touchListener will listen once you will touch that view, then repeatedly call until up event occurs .

so in my understanding , handle tv2 touch by calculate x,y coordinates in the only way